# Getting CROSS SLOT error in redis for delete command

Tags: redis

I am trying to run delete command on redis(from spring boot app), I am getting cross slot error. As per the documentation this error occurs only for multi key commands, however running delete command for single key is giving this error.

Comment: This is probably be because they key in question is not on the node your code is connected to. Can you share some details about your configuration both for Spring Boot and your Redis cluster?